# prevent special character in ajax (http)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/pos/' + myVar
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {}
..
```

myVar's value is a-b but it's not consistent, it may be a->b, how could I prevent it to become -%3E?

Comment: try `encodeURIComponent(myVar)`

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want it get the data to get encoded?

Answer (score 0):

If the result URL becomes `/pos/myVar` you can use `'/pos/'+encodeURIComponent(myVar)`. i.e.,

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/pos/' + encodeURIComponent(myVar),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {}
});
```

Else if your result URL becomes `/pos/myVar_name=myVar_value`, then you should try the following :-

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/pos/',
        data:{myVar_name:"myVar_value"}, /*---*/
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {}
});
```

This method will automatically encode the required data in the name and value.